# How to remove the hover behavior of button in navbar?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this navbar for my website im building using angular. The color of the navbar is gray and i have this hamburger icon. When you click it a drop menu appears with link to different pages. One of my pages "Projects" when you hover over it has dropdown menu with the individual links to my certain projects. It works fine, however whenever i hover over projects, there's this black rectangle box behind it and i want it where it doesn't appear when i hover over "Projects", any idea of how to get rid of this? *ignore the links as they're all the same right now as their individual pages aren't done yet

[Here is a picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XprBz.png)

```
<li class="nav-item">
        <button class="links bg-dark" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter('projNavbar')" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#projNavbar" aria-controls="projNavbar" aria-expanded="false" style="border: none;">
                    <a class="nav-link links"
                        routerLink="/" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Projects</a>
        </button>
      </li>
      <div id="projNavbar" #projNavbar (mouseleave)="mouseLeave('projNavbar')" class="collapse navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item mr-auto" [ngStyle]="{'width.px': .25*max(winWidth, winHeight)}">
                <a class=" text text-left nav-link mx-auto"
                    [ngStyle]="{'font-size.vw': fontSize*.5, 'font-style': 'italic', 'width': '50%'}"
                    routerLink="/"
                    (click)="closeAll(['projNavbar', 'mainNavbar'])">Project 1</a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mr-auto" [ngStyle]="{'width.px': .25*max(winWidth, winHeight)}">
                <a class="text text-left mx-auto nav-link"
                    [ngStyle]="{'font-size.vw': fontSize*.5, 'font-style': 'italic',  'width': '50%'}"
                    routerLink="/" (click)="closeAll(['projNavbar', 'mainNavbar'])">Project 2</a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mr-auto" [ngStyle]="{'width.px': .25*max(winWidth, winHeight)}">
                <a class="text text-left mx-auto nav-link"
                    [ngStyle]="{'font-size.vw': fontSize*.5, 'font-style': 'italic',  'width': '50%'}"
                    routerLink="/" (click)="closeAll(['projNavbar', 'mainNavbar'])">Project 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult to discern the exact issue without seeing your styles or a live demo, but I'd reckon the anchor is just dynamically having a dark background-color applied to it. To override that, this single CSS property should do the trick:

```css
.nav-item,
.nav-item > button.links,
.nav-item > button.links > a.nav-link {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```